# Force footer on bottom

Tags: html, css

Ok i have problem to force footer on bottom when not enough content to push it there naturally.

I partially solved problem. It is rly simple design, i have header, content and footer, all inside div wrapper.

```
html,
body {

margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
font: sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}

#content {
padding: 2% 5%;
max-width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom:80px; /* Height of the footer element */
clear: both;
background-color: yellow;
}

footer {
background:#ffab62;
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
font-size: 0.75em;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 30px;
clear: both;
color: #ccc;
}
```

I have used background color to see position of elements on page. So when there is not enough content footer is on bottom and it is OK. When there is more than enough content footer is overlapping some of it, it gets fixed when i put position on footer relative instead of absolute but then on pages where there is not enough content footer is not on bottom.. Fixing one other is not good and fixing that other first page is not good.. Is there any solution that can help me solve this...

Comment: Is it possible for us to see demo or have html code too?

Comment: This is a classic problem; with several different scenarios, more code / full code or a online demo would help!

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your `min-height:` to the minimum value where you want your footer to end up, `100%` will put it right below your content *(which should be the default anyway without even declaring)* which you said isn't long enough; make a `minimum-height: 900px;` or similar to where you want the minimum end point to be where the footer will live.

*If* the footer is in the correct place in the HTML but it is floating up. Then consider the below.

```
display:inline-block;
```

add to footer.

```
footer {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

If these don't work, show your HTML!

Comment: Can you explain more detailed to me, i dont understand which element you think about when you say adjust your min-height.. ?

It is rly simple model, as i said, header, content and footer, all inside div named wrapper.. All i want is footer to be on bottom when there is not enough content, but when there is enough content i dont want footer to overlap it as it is doing right now with this styles i have applied... And i want to do it in plain html / css no JS or jQuery solution..

Comment: Can you post your FULL code including HTML on here or inside a jsfiddle.net demo, and I'll give you the answer ;)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/be7dm7sn/

I am thinking about other option now. I have header, content and footer, so if i make header fixed height i can do min-height to content calc(100%-header-footer) or to use instead of 100% inside calc func this new vh (viewport) in CSS ?

Comment: So... looking at your fiddle, what is your current problem? seems like the footer remains in place, even if i zoom out?

Comment: change where you have min-height: 100%; to the actual minimu height you would like the container to be regardless of content

Comment: My problem is when i have more content, example i sent you with lorem ipsum text, footer is overlapping some of it... When i do not have enough content it is all OK, footer on fixed on bottom, but when i do have more than enough content footer wont stay under content class but overlaps it..

Comment: wrap your text content in a wrapper with 100% height. have your main wrapper have a MIN-HEIGHT: (smallest size, use pixels). AND HAVE A MAX-HEIGHT for your main wrapper as well (pixels), for the maximum height. Now for regular height: have 100% get it? give that a try

Comment: can you please edit code on fiddle i sent you and send me back, cause i do not understand you to be honest.. Maybe i will better understand from looking code..

Answer (score 0):

You nearly did it :)

Your content div is overlaping the sticky footer because of its height. Just use a height: calc(100% - footer_height); and start your content where your header finishes.

This is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naeb6c0m/) example of this usage.

CSS file

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.header {
    background: #d6d6d6;
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    background: yellow;
}
.footer {
    background: #d6d6d6;
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

I hope it is useful.

Comment: Ok, now my content is not being overlapped by footer but it is now overlapping header..

Comment: And it is not that my content div overlapping footer, it is footer that overlaps content cause it is fixed on bottom and have fixed height so when i have a lot of content footer is overlapping it. And if i change position to relative for footer, on page where there is enough content it will be fine and footer just under content but on page where there is not enough content footer is on middle of screen again...

Comment: Yeah it seems that you are right. I copied some lorem text in the content and it overlaped. Trying a few other things.